# "\includegraphics{}" but for .pgf files?

Tags: pgfplots, macros, external-files, strings

I'm trying to implement a command that makes it easier to put .pgf files in my document (plots from matplotlib), similar to how `\includegraphics[scale=...]{...}` works for image files. However, because .pgf files use the `input{}` command, this is a bit more difficult.

Normally, the way I display .pgf figures is:

```
\begin{figure}
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\input{"../Parent_Dir/filename.pgf"}}
\end{figure}
```

But it would be nice to do all of this in one swift command.

So I want something like a bit like this:

```
\newcommand{\pgfpath}{"../Parent_Dir"}
\newcommand{\includepgf}[2][0.5\textwidth]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{\input{\pgfpath#2.pgf}}}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I'm having some trouble escaping the file path name, since I use underscores in my file paths, and the command `\textwidth` in the optional scaling argument seems to throw errors.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: if you have  a form that works as in your first code block, a newcommand will work fine. I note that you used `"` in tke first form but not in the second. You should not need `"` in current latex but perhaps you have an old release.  Saying "it does not work" does not allow anyone to help, please provide a test file that shows the error and show the exact error messae that you get in the log file

Comment: Do you know about `gincltex`? http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/gincltex/gincltex.pdf

Comment: underscores are not an issue in file paths unless you have some very non standad settings

Comment: I would try the graphics driver provided by tikzscale package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide an example, or say what error you got but if the first form that you show works, the second form below will work. Note that your suggested code is missing `/` between the path name and the file name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\input{"../Parent_Dir/filename.pgf"}}
\end{figure}


\newcommand{\pgfpath}{../Parent_Dir}
\newcommand\zz[2][0.5\textwidth]{\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\input{"\pgfpath/#2.pgf"}}}

\zz{filename}

\end{document}
```

quoting with `"` is not needed in a current latex but perhaps you have an old release, you did not say. I left in the quotes here.

Comment: Well that was a silly error that wasted much of my time! I used the quotes to make sure the underscore in the file paths was interpreted correctly; I did not realize this was not an issue! Thank you!

Comment: underscores have absolutely no effect on the underscore, they are a primitive pdftex feature to allow spaces in filenames but current latex removes any the user adds and adds some itself around the resulting filename. so adding them explicitly doesn't hurt but doesn't do anythg at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xparse` to bring in `\NewDocumentCommand`. Then you can write

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\includepgf}{ O{0.5\textwidth} v }{%
   \resizebox{#1}{!}{\input{\pgfpath#2.pgf}}%
}
```

to define your command which will make sure that special commands in the required argument aren't misinterpreted.

Comment: `xparse` package not needed in current latex.